# Is it bad form to invoke a function inside ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*This question is about performance in AngularJS, not coding style. (Having said that, if it is terrible form to be using ng-repeat in 2017, please tell me!)*

I find myself writing lots of lists with ng-repeat and applying a special style with ng-class to indicate which item is selected.

However, I'm always flip-flopping between strategies. I want to know if there is a definitive "best" way to indicate a selected item in a list. In this case, my primary goal is the best performance possible.

option A - add a property like "isSelected" to the item; when true, add class via ng-class

option B - for each item in the list, invoke a function to check if it's selected

option C - take the logic from the function in Option B and put it directly in the DOM, saving a function call

I prefer option B because I don't have to mutate the object with an unnecessary property. However, the check is done inside an ng-repeat, so that means the function would be getting called dozens of times. The logic itself is pretty cheap, as you can see below, but is there any overheard for calling this inside a $digest?

Does it even matter which I choose?

```
<!-- option A -->
<li ng-repeat"item in myItems"
    ng-class={ 'active': item.isSelected }">

<!-- option B -->
<li ng-repeat"item in myItems"
    ng-class={ 'active': vm.isItemSelected(item.code) }">

<!-- Option C --> 
<li ng-repeat"item in myItems"
    ng-class={ 'active': vm.itemCodeSelected === item.code }">
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it's no worse than invoking a function in a scope expression anywhere else in the view.

Scope expressions are evaluated every digest cycle, whether they're in ngClass or ngStyle or ngShow or anywhere else.

Comment: I should add that this is true unless the scope expression is a one-time binding using the `{{:: expression }}` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Option C
You can create a function and call it in your list item click. than you compare selected item with item itself

```
select(item) {
   $scope.selected = item
}
```

and use it like this

```
<li ng-repeat"item in myItems"
    ng-click="$scope.select(item)"
    ng-class={ 'active': item == $scope.selected }">
```

this way nothing is checked while ng-repeat is doing its job, you dont mutate your object

Comment: The `$scope` reference in your expression is wrong. And the scope expression is still evaluated on every digest cycle. It just doesn't need to call a function, making it ever so slightly faster.

Comment: @JCFord $scope reference depend on angular version, so this is not the point. And the expresion evaluation is not the same as calling a function that search in all array elements to find the match. So this is the best way ever you can use in this scenario

Comment: fwiw i am running 1.5.7

Comment: @user2954463 as you are refering to your controller with **vm** than replace $scope with vm and u done